# Warning from ngrx about runtime checks

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I upgraded my app from Angular 7 to Angular 8 using `ng update`. When I run it via `ng serve`, There's a warning printed in my console from `ngrx`:

```
@ngrx/store: runtime checks are currently opt-in but will be the default in the next major version with the possibility to opt-out, see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8 for more information.
```

The documentation at the provided link talks about `ngrx-store-freeze` being deprecated. However, my application does not use `ngrx-store-freeze`, and I have no idea what a "runtime check" is. What do I need to change in my code to address the source of this warning?

Comment: what version of ngrx is referenced in packagej.json file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This warning is coming because in NGRX < 8, to make store immutable, we need to use ngrx-store-freeze library. In NGRX 8, you can opt-in to make store immutable without ngrx-store-freeze [as it is in build now in NGRX 8]. This warning will go away if you opt in-store immutability by specifying `runtimeChecks` property in `StoreModule.forRoot` like this:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true
      }      
    })
```

Example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true
      }      
    }),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Ref: https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-8-ngrx-data-create-functions-runtime-checks-and-mock-selectors-a44fac112627

Hope this helps.